# Enable double-click removal of cell color

Tags: javascript

I created a pixel art maker with vanilla JavaScript and would like to add functionality that enables the user to double-click a cell to clear its color.

I tried adding the following, but it didn't work. (I also tried replacing 'this' with 'event.target'.)

```
pixelCanvas.addEventListener('dblclick', 'td', function() {
  this.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

For reference please view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to addEventListener should be a function.

```
pixelCanvas.addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = null;
});
```

When you want to change an element's style, do it through the element's `style` property, not through `removeAttribute`.